# images not loading when changing base url in angular JS project

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-routing

I want to change the base url

when load the application url is http://localhost:4200/#/ I want to change this to http://localhost:4200/carrom/.

For doing this I changed base url to  then loading url is http://localhost:4200/carrom#/

How can I change this to http://localhost:4200/carrom...but the images and assets are not loading

For doing this I changed base url to  then loading url is http://localhost:4200/carrom#/

Comment: The problem is how you define the "src" of your images.the correct is, see that there's no "./" or "../.../" : `<img src="assets/images/img1.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

From what I could make out, you could do either of the below.

1. Set up routes so that the base url "/" loads the carrom component.

   const routes: Routes = [{
   path: '',
   component: CarromComponent
   },
   {
   path: 'home',
   component: HomeComponent
   },
   {
   path: '**',
   component: PageNotFoundComponent
   }, // Wildcard route for a 404 page
   ];

Or call navigate on HomeComponent load

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router){
   this.navigate()
  }

  navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['/carrom']) // assuming this the route of the carrom component
  }
}
```

Comment: but how do we inject router object in Home Component

Comment: You won't be adding routing to the page, but the entire application.
https://www.samjulien.com/add-routing-existing-angular-project

Just thought of another hacky way of doing it, look for <app-component></app-component> and replace it with <carrom-component></carrom-component>.

This is not the right way of doing it, but will achieve what you want temporarily